# Clunky arg check in Python

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I have a function:

```
def check_user(self, **args):
    allowed = ['name', 'screen_name', 'url', 'description', 'location']
    arg_check = [val for val in args if val not in allowed]
    if arg_check:
        raise ValueError('Invalid args: ' + ' '.join(arg_check))
```

And it works, but it feels very unpythonic. Is there a better way of checking this? I was hoping to not have to write a big if/else statement.

This way I can iterate over the args in a loop easily.

Comment: Presumably you have multiple `check_...` functions... why not abstract the list comprehension and test into a separate function?  `check_allowed(['name', ...], args)`

Comment: why dont you just ignore unwanted args?

Comment: Why are you checking in the first place?

Comment: They're columns in a database table. I want to iterate over the passed in args and query the DB, then check that they all come from the same entry else resolve the differences in a function higher up.

Answer (score 10):

I think a more pythonic version would explicitly declare the allowed arguments in the function definition. Just replace `None` with your default values.

```
def check_user(self, name=None, screen_name=None, url=None,
               description=None, location=None):
    # Do something here
    # ...
```

Comment: Can you then easily iterate over the args that are not None?

Comment: No, you would have to go through each argument separately. However, if you don't want any argument to be `None` you should let the error come from trying to use a `None` valued argument. This will provide a more informative error message. Optionally you could use positional arguments instead of keyword arguments, forcing the user to supply values for all the function parameters.